# geom_smooth: what is its meaning (why is it lower than the mean?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I have data on the number of trips people make to work per week. Along with the distance of the trip, I am interested in the relationship between the two variables. (Frequency is expected to fall as distance increases, essentially a negative relationship.) Cor.test supports this hypothesis: -0.08993444 with a p value of 2.2e-16.

When I come to plot this, the distance clearly tends to decrease for more frequent trips. To make sense of the vast number of points I used geom_smooth. But I don't fully understand the result. According to the [help pages](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_smooth.html), it's a "conditional mean". However, it seems never to approach the true mean,

```
> mean(aggs3$Distance)
[1] 9.766497
```

in the plot below, which seems never to go above 8.
What's going on here? I think I really want the rolling mean, but found [rollmean](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/zoo/html/rollmean.html) from the zoo package a hassle to implement (you need to sort the data first), and I would like to ask for the optimal solution before forging ahead. Many thanks.

[image: geom_smooth]

```
p <- ggplot(data=aggs3, aes(x=N.trips.week, y=Distance))
p + geom_point(alpha = 0.1) + geom_smooth() +
  ylim(0,30) + xlim(0,25)  + ylab("Distance (miles)") +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom="polygon", alpha=0.5,na.rm=T, se=0.1)
```

(Secondary unrelated question: how do I make the 2d density layer contours smoother?)

(P.s. I know there are better ways to visualise this - e.g. below, but I for the sake of learning I need better understanding of how to use geom_smooth.)

[image: histogram]

Comment: Assuming you used `geom_smooth` with its default settings, what you're seeing is in fact a "rolling mean", in the sense that the `loess` method used is essentially fitting a model using local averaging. Although the quadratic nature of the default may be conflicting with your simple "rolling mean" expectations.

Comment: Come on. Yu didn't really show us that data. You stuck ylim=c(0,30) and there could easiy have been some freak 9999's value in the distance values distorting the mean. The loess estimates are not sensitive to that effect. Show us `max(eggs$Distance)` and `tail(sort(eggs$Distance))`.

Comment: @DWin: Unless the bar chart was similarly truncated there no values above 100.

Comment: @RoyalTS: So what the values in the first two columns of the barchart that are plotted darkgreen that are NOT displayed in the legend and are presumably above 100???

Comment: Ah! You have way better eyes than I do apparently. Apologies!

Answer (score 3):

The curve `geom_smooth` produces is indeed an estimate of the conditional mean function, i.e. it's an estimate of the mean distance in miles *conditional on the number of trips per week* (it's a particular kind of estimator called LOESS). The number you calculate, in contrast, is an estimate for the *unconditional* mean, i.e. the mean over all the data.

If it's the relationship between the two variables you're interested in there are plenty of ways you could model that. If you just want a linear relationship, fitting a linear model (`lm()`) will do the trick and if that's what you want to plot, passing `method='lm'` as an argument to `geom_smooth` will show you what that looks like. But your data really doesn't look like there's just a simple linear relationship between the two variables so you may want to think a bit harder about what it is exactly you want to do!

Comment: what about that grey band around the mean, what is that ? is that a confidence band ?

Comment: @Ray Kodiak Yes it is

Comment: anyone happens to know where I can find a precise documentation for what the `method`s I can pass to `geom_smooth` _really_ do? Also: how to get the result of e.g. a linear fit as coefficients a, b for y = a x + b?